# PostMapping в программе, Java, Spring

Tags: java, html, spring

Есть у меня две формы c post

```
<form name="form1" method="post"> 
...
</form>

<form name="form2" method="post"> 
...
</form>
```

Я хочу их по разному обрабатывать контроллером, но чтобы после обработки адрес страницы не изменялся(чтобы всегда оставалось blabla/schelude).

```
@PostMapping("/schedule")
public String putMessageInDB()
...
    return "schedule";
}

@PostMapping("/schedule")
public String deleteMessageInDB()
...
    return "schedule";
}
```

Пробывал через action = "deleteFromDb", но тогда в адресе станицы отображалось blabla/deleteFromDb.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action = "deleteFromDb"> 
...
</form>
```

.

```
@PostMapping("deleteFromDb")
public String deleteMessageInDB()
...
    return "schedule";
}
```

Как обрабатывать два пост запроса в одном контроллере, чтобы адрес страницы не менялся?

Comment: Сформулируйте свою мысль корректно и измените свой пост, ибо ничего не понятно что Вы хотите сделать. И у вас маппинг форм одинаковый, работать - не будет

Comment: Так в это и проблема, я хочу, чтобы при отправлении разных пост запросов происходили разные действия, а адрес страницы не менялся.

Comment: То есть, что бы при одинаковом постмапинге выполнялись разные действия.

Comment: Какой адресс станицы? Вглядитесь в контроллер и мапинг - у Вас одинаковый маппинг, запросы не будут работать!

Comment: Так я и не говорил, что они работают, а лишь обрисовал картину, как бы я хотел, что бы это выглядело. То есть чтобы после двух разных мапингов адрес страницы оставался http://localhost:8080/schedule

Comment: Еще раз - "/schedule" этот маппинг не будет работать для двух методов, измените его на разные, и адрес не будет менятся

Comment: А как программа поймет, какой метод вызывать при отправке разных форм с методом post?

Comment: Ну так Вы же должны указать URI в скрипте отправки формы или непосредственно в форме action="/schedule"

Comment: Хорошо, а второй тогда как назвать?

Comment: Да как хотите, уважаемый, учите Spring

Comment: У меня все равно меняется адрес страницы, при разных action
http://localhost:8080/schedule
http://localhost:8080/schedule2
<form name="form1" method="post" action="/schedule"> 
...
</form>

<form name="form2" method="post" action="/schedule2"> 
...
</form>

Comment: @PostMapping("/schedule")
    public String putMessageInDB()
        ...
        return "schedule";
    }

    @PostMapping("/schedule2")
    public String deleteMessageFromDb()
        ...
        return "schedule";
    }

Comment: Так что делать, подскажите пожалуйста? Я просто не программирую с 14 лет, как Вы, и, возможно, не понимаю такие очевидные для Вас вещи.

Comment: если путь меняется, то у Вас не срабатывает маппинг спринга, смотрите лог запуска как маппятся ссылки. Что показывает дебаг?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать @ DeleteMapping("deleteFromDb") и @ PostMapping("deleteFromDb"). Но в таком случае вам нам будет запрос слать не через форму, а через жс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, надо использовать разные http-методы

**Контроллер**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/schedule", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String putMessageInDB()
    ...
    return "schedule";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/schedule", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteMessageInDB()
    ...
    return "schedule";
}
```

**Шаблон**

```
<form name="form1" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    ...
</form>

<form name="form2" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    ...
</form>
```

**web.xml**

```
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что было нужно!